# Test if Eloquent Observer`s method fires an event

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.5

The app I am working on fires an event, when one of the Eloquent model attributes is updated.

The Eloquent model is called `Job` and it is supposed to fire `JobCustomerTotalAmountDueChanged` when the `duration` attribute is updated. I have the following code in the `JobObserver`:

```
public function saved(Job $job)
{
    if ($job->isDirty('duration')) {
        event(new JobCustomerTotalAmountDueChanged($job));
    }
}
```

When I try to test it using `Event::fake`, Eloquent events are not being fired, which means that the code in `saved` method is never execured. From what I see the `assertDispatched` and `assertNotDispatched` methods are only available for faked events. Is there a way to assert that a particular event is/is not fired without `Event::fake`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution turned out to be very easy after all:

Laravel lets you specify which events should be faked, as an argument to `fake` method. In my example:

```
Event::fake([JobCustomerTotalAmountDueChanged::class])
```

All of the other events are being triggered and handled. Also, you can make assertions only with reference to events passed as argument to `fake` method. If you don't pass any argument, Laravel will try to 'fake' every event in the app.

Comment: Amade, I'm trying to pass in the argument my specific event, have you any idea about why even doing this the model events are not being fired? I'm using spatie/laravel-sluggable package, and the slug is not being generated beacause the creating method is not being fired, what results in an mysql error for me because the slug field can't be null.

Comment: This was added in Laravel 5.5. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 5.6.26, so in theory should work. I'm stuck whit this

Comment: Maybe you're calling Event::fake() without arguments somewhere? Also, you're not faking eloquent events, right?

Comment: I just check, I'm not calling Event::fake() without arguments anywhere else. And no, I'm just  trying to fake my custom event.

Comment: I think I just ran into the same issue as you. Looks like Eloquent events are not being fired. There is a workaround for it though. Check out the last answer (from November 2017) here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18066

Comment: Thanks Amade, I'll use this hacky solution for now.